# Android, Kotlin : How to invoke MainActivity's method into sub class method in case of kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to invoke a MainActivity's method from a sub class. Look my code bellow.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    open fun action(v: View){
        sub_class().test()
    }

    open fun toast(s: String){
        Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    open class sub_class{
        open fun test(){
            val a = MainActivity()
            a.toast("test")
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to invoke the `toast()` method into `sub_class()`. App crashed when I try to do that.

**Note :** Like this program work in **Intellij Idea**. I can't understand why this program don't work on app.

Comment: Please provide the error or stacktrace you are getting

Comment: Make your method public

Comment: I make all methods and class public. but not working.

Comment: @sharifulislam if changing the modifier from `private` to `protected` does not work; it is very likely, that it has a whole other problem, beside that. add stack-trace; "does not work" is not an error description.

Comment: **NOTE**: You can't initialize the activity explicitly. Therefore this code `val a = MainActivity()` will not work as expected.

Comment: @Enzokie what can I do in in this case? I am new on kotlin.

Comment: I didn't notice that your `sub_class` is not an inner class therefore your subclass can't call the Toast directly from MainActivity.

Comment: @MartinZeitler is there any way to invoke main class method from sub class in kolin in android studio?

Comment: Do not instantiate Activities manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub_class is actually a Nested class. And you probably want to make it an Inner class. ([Nested and Inner Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html))
Inner classes can access members of outer class as they carry a reference to an object of an outer class. So you don't need to create an instance of an outer class within an inner class.

In your case it will be like this:

```
open inner class sub_class{
        open fun test(){
            toast("test")
        }
    }
```